# How to save LinearLayout as image after drawing (finger painting) on it

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am new to android, and creating a small application where I want to get an image from gallery and then after drawing on it (using finger paint) save it.

The problem I am having is after drawing, when I try to save the image it only saves the drawing with black background. The image taken from the gallery is not visible in the saved image.

**After drawing on an image and saving it**:

[image]

**Actual Image saved**:

[image]

**Layout**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#FFCCCCCC"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context=".ImageActivity" >

 <!-- layout for displaying save button -->
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/my_save_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/save"
        android:src="@drawable/save" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <!-- layout that displays image taken from gallery and allows to finger paint-->
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/my_view_drawing_pad1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_view_drawing_pad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**ImageActivity.java** onClick method to save image:

```
@Override
   public void onClick(View view) 
   {
      drawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);    
      String imgSaved = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
            getContentResolver(), drawView.getDrawingCache(), UUID.randomUUID()
            .toString() + ".png", "drawing");

      if (imgSaved != null) 
      {
         Toast savedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Drawing saved to Gallery!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
         savedToast.show();
      } else {
               Toast unsavedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Oops! Image could not be saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

               unsavedToast.show();
             }
      drawView.destroyDrawingCache();
   }
```

Could you please tell me, what am I missing here. Why my image is saved with black background?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a screen shot of the root layout and convert it into bitmap image and save it like following :

```
 LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_layout); 

    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    v.buildDrawingCache(true);

    saveBm = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());

    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Save this bitmap image where ever you want.

Comment: Thanks for this.  
Could you please add   **LinearLayout vi = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_view_drawing_pad1);** at the top of your answer. This might help other newbie like me.